# Unexpected result when trying to match against the arguments of Times

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the following question:

```
Reap[a b c d /. (x_ a /; (! MemberQ[Sow[x], b])) :>  Subscript[a, x]]  
(* ===> {b Subscript[a, c d], {{b c d, b c, b d, c d}}} *)
```

In my thought, nothing will happen, because `b` is a Member of `b c d`.

I can understand `MemberQ` use `b c d` as its argument, but why `MemberQ` also test `{b c, b d, c d}`?

Consider another question:

```
Reap[a b c d /. (x_. a /; (! MemberQ[Sow[x], b])) :>  Subscript[a, x]]
(* ===> {{b c d Subscript[a, 1], {{b c d, 1}}}*)
```

Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you use `Print[x]; Sow[x]`?

Comment: @J.M.isback.  Thank you, but Print[x] will not give me a clear understand of the MemberQ's behavior.

Comment: But you get to see exactly what is being `Sow[]`-n, no?

Comment: This behavior is really related more with [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) and not with [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html). Check for example this snippet `a b c d /. x_ a /; Print[x] :> "never reached"`. Is its behavior clear to you?

Comment: @jkuczm Thank you for your help, but that's what I don't understand. when `x=b c`, for example, then `x a=a b c`, which is not equal to the original expression, `a b c d`.  So why `x=b c` will trigger the pattern matching?

Comment: It's due to [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) attribute of `Times`. Consider: `SetAttributes[f, Flat]; 
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[a, x_] /; Print[x] :> "never reached"`

Comment: `Times` has also [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute, which causes tests of all permutations of it's arguments. `SetAttributes[g, Orderless]; 
g[a, b] /. g[x_, y_] /; Print[x, " ", y] :> "never reached"`

Comment: Also [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) of `Times` is `1` which is partly responsible for your last example. Check: `Default[h] = 1; 
h[a] /. h[x_., y_] /; Print[x, " ", y] :> "never reached"`. Combination of `Times` attributes makes it really complicated when comes to understanding its pattern matching.

Comment: @jkuczm Thanks for your replies, they give me a thorough understanding. :)